# Do all relational databases have same syntax

Tags: sql

I have been using MySQL and PostgreSQL for a while. I want to learn more about relational databases. I want to work with other databases like SQL Server etc. So, **do all relational databases have the same syntax?**

Comment: In theory yes, in reality no.

Comment: No, mysql and postgresql already differ in dialect.

Comment: *Does all relational databases have the same syntax.* No. Only the most base syntax is the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there standard sql that works in all database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100619/is-there-standard-sql-that-works-in-all-database)

Answer (score 1):

You already know two databases, so you should be aware that there are differences in syntax.  For instance, MySQL supports:

```
select now() + interval 1 day
```

But Postgres does not.

The basic SQL structure is the same -- all databases support `SELECT`, `FROM`, `GROUP BY`, and similar constructs.  However, there are definitely differences among databases.  Much of what you have learned will apply to other databases, but it is worth testing to be sure that it works and does what you intend.

Comment: *But Postgres does not.* In Postgre it looks like `select now() + interval '1 day'`.